# How to set viewing privileges to different users in joomla

Tags: joomla, access-control

I have 4 pages

1. home
2. management
3. services
4. contact us

I have 3 type of users

1. public user
2. broker
3. supplier

I want when a "Broker" logs in to the website. he/she can only view home page and services. Not other pages. likewise when a supplier logs in to the web page he should see only management and contact us and home page.

I know in Joomla has 8 user types (Author,Editor.. etc) but I want to customize my own user types accordingly. These users only need Viewing to certain areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using J1.5 and the ACL is not that sophisticated. You have basically 2 choices - you can buy a 3rd party ACL that gives you better control or you can upgrade to J1.7. With end of life coming for 1.5 in April 2012, it would be a waste to go down that path. I would upgrade to 1.7, then install ACL Manager and set it up how ever you like.

Comment: Hi Brent. Thanks for the reply. but ACL manager extension also commercial rite. its not free of charge.

Comment: It is commercial, but only 10 euros, and WELL worth the price. It is open source so you can install it on as many domains as you want. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/backend-a-full-access-control/17951

You can accomplish the same thing without ACL manager, but this makes it WAY easier.

Comment: Hi Brent. Can you tell me to achieve the results without ACL Manager. Can we viewing permissions to different users. ?

Comment: Permissions can be viewed/modified within each component that supports ACL. So for example in the Module Manager you can set the permissions by clicking the Options icon when in the Module Manager. Same with the Menu Manager, User Manager, and most other components that support ACL. Look for the Options icon on the main page of the component.